# What's roughly the lowest price range for accommodation in Nakhchivan?

Tags: budget, accommodation, azerbaijan, caucasus, rates

It turns out that Azerbaijan has an exclave called Nakhchivan which shares a border with Turkey.

Haven't heard of it? Well it seems neither have most of the websites I use to get an idea how much it will cost to sleep there. HostelWorld, HostelBookers, TripAdvisor, WikiTravel, either have no information on the place at all or list hotels with no indication whatsoever on how much they cost.

**So how much can a budget traveller expect to have to pay to sleep in Nakhchivan?**

Comment: Have you to tried to play with the spelling of the place. I have the impression that every time I read about this region, the spelling changes ... On the English Wikipedia, they list the following ways to spell the place: Nakhichevan, Naxcivan, Naxçivan, Nachidsheuan, Nakhijevan, Nakhchawan, Nakhitchevan, Nakhjavan, Nakhdjevan. And I know that there exist different spelings in German and in French.

Comment: I did link several of the spellings together with "OR" in my google searches. Also Google is pretty good at finding hits with variant spellings. But I might try again making sure to include all of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Dörtyol Ticaret Merkezi Misafirhanesi**, which apparently means "trade centre guesthouse" had a room with shared bathroom available for ***12 Azeri manat*** as of August last year.
That's about *11 euro* or *$15 USD* currently.

This comes from somebody calling themself ["MoonStarFarAway"](http://www.travbuddy.com/MoonStarFarAway) on [a site called `travbuddy.com`](http://www.travbuddy.com/Drtyol-Ticaret-Merkezi-Misafirhanesi-v456420)

Apparently the cheapest option according to the author.

Answer (score 7):

Am also struggling to find any info on it.

Some hotel costs from the area are observed on a [blog of the region.](http://www.futtrup.name/Ararat/Nakhchivan.html)

I also *love* the fact that one of the hotels of the region has the song 'Hotel California' [playing on their website](http://www.otelakdamar.com/)...

Comment: Yes it's clear now that Eagles are nothing more than plagiarists profiting off the commercialisation of Nakhchivan cultural assets. Maybe we can finally find out what "colitas" means. Besides that it's a bit unclear whether the 100 Turkish lira mentioned in one place was the price for the taxi or the hotel but that would be pretty shocking for a taxi ride!

Comment: Note that the "Otel Akdamar" that Mark Mayo mentions is located in Van, Turkey. From there to Nakhchivan city is at least a 6 hours drive. According to the blog cited in Mark's post Nakhchivan to Igdir took 3 hours. Add then 3 hours from Igdir to Van.

Comment: Sadly I think I should mention that just the day following asking this question a 7.2 earthquake has hit Van, Turkey with 75 dead so far )-:

Comment: uh yes, about that quake, I think they've said over 1000 dead now...

Answer (score 2):

For Nahkchivan you're probably better off using local tourist agencies. Search for "nakhchivan tours" on the internet and you'll find a couple companies that can give you more listings than the major booking websites.

While this might not get you the cheapest accommodation, the thing with Azerbaijan is that there's this registration rule for visitors (see: https://caravanistan.com/visa/azerbaijan/registration/)

If your duration of stay is shorter than the registration timeframe then it's probably not an issue, otherwise the budget/family-run accommodations might not be doing the registration for you, and you risk getting fined when you leave the country (although I'm not sure how strictly enforced this is). This happened to me a few years ago when I had only 3 days to register but my hostel wouldn't do that for me. I wasted a whole day running between various super bureaucratic Azeri government agencies to try to get myself registered, who simply passes me around like a ball. Finally I walked into a fancy hotel asking for help and they point me to the right direction.

tl;dr
If you have a stay longer than the registration timeframe or have complicated logistics, go with a commercial hotel through a local travel agency. It might cost you around US$50-70 instead of the $15 budget hostels but the Azeri government is not something you want to deal with, especially if you're only there for a short time.